# Есть ли ошибка в строке

Tags: python, python-3.x

x<sub>0</sub> = a, x<sub>i</sub> = px<sub>x-1</sub> + q, i = 1, 2, 3 ...
Дано положительное челое число n и действительное число a, c, d, p, q.
Найти принадлежит ли число x<sub>n</sub> интервалу (c, d).

```
n = int(input("n = "))
a = float(input("a = "))
c = float(input("c = "))
d = float(input("d = "))
p = float(input("p = "))
q = float(input("q = "))
xn = a * p ** n + q * (1 - p ** n) / (1 - p) #Интересует эта строка
print(xn)
if c <= xn <= d:
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

Правильно ли будет считать x<sub>n</sub>, у меня есть какие-то опасения в строке где есть коментарий

Comment: Да, верно. У меня та же формула. Только для n < 0 она вроде не работает, но я предполагаю, что имелось в виду натуральное.

Comment: для n < 0 она и не должна работать по условию задачи :)

Comment: @Zhihar Для n < 0 можно очевидным образом выразить формулу для f(i - 1) через f(i), так что по условию вполне может быть. Просто в нормальной задаче подразумевается целое неотрицательное или вообще строго положительное, но это именно подразумевается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну формула то с небольшим дефектом :)

действительно

```
xn = a * p^n + q * (p^(n - 1) + p^(n-2) + ... + p + 1)
```

и `(p^(n - 1) + p^(n-2) + ... + p + 1)` как сумма геометрической прогрессии сворачивается в

```
(p^n - 1) / (p - 1)
```

но что делать, когда `p = 1`?

тогда эта сумма сворачивается в `n`

Поэтому или учитывайте 2 случая в вычислениях или считайте сумму напрямую, а не через формулу суммы геометрической прогрессии

типа такого:

```
nx = (a * p**n + q * (1 - p**n) / (1 - p)) if p != 1 else (a * p**n + q * n)
```